# Finetuning FindBugs ant task in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, findbugs

Within eclipse I am able to define **detector ids** and **bug categories** to be reported from the preference page.

I can't find anything like that for the FindBugs ant task in the [FindBugs docs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/anttask.html) or using autocomplete inside the Eclipse ant editor.

The things I can adjust are the **effort** and the **report level**.

Is adjusting the detectors and categories an undocumented or a missing feature or have I missed something? And how is it solved in the FindBugs Eclipse plugin?

Answer (score 9):

I had some issues with findbugs and ant as well. Here is what I've done finally:

```
<taskdef name="findbugs" 
            classpathref="build_libs" 
            classname="edu.umd.cs.findbugs.anttask.FindBugsTask" />
    <!-- 
     Executes findbugs for a unpacked plugin (folder)                    
     Params:
       plugin: the plugin / module to fetch
       plugin_dir: the folder to checkout the plugin to
    -->
    <target name="run.findbugs">
        <echo level="info">Running FindBugs:  ${plugin}</echo>
        <findbugs home="${FINDBUGS.HOME}" 
            output="xml:withMessages" 
            outputFile="${report.dir}/findbugs_report_${plugin}.xml" 
            timeout="1200000" 
            includefilter="report/YOUR_findbugs_filter.xml"
            excludefilter="report/YOUR_findbugs_exclude_filter.xml" 
            jvmargs="-server -Xss1m -Xmx512m">

            <sourcepath location="${plugin_dir}/${plugin}/**/*.java" />
            <class location="${install}/plugins/${plugin}_*.jar" />
        </findbugs>
    </target>

    <!-- 
     Executes findbugs for a single eclipse plugin                 
     Params:
       plugin: the plugin / module to fetch
       plugin_dir: the folder to checkout the plugin to
    -->
    <target name="run.findbugs.unpacked">
        <echo level="info">Running FindBugs:  ${plugin} (unpacked)</echo>
        <path id="rfu.pfp">
            <fileset dir="${install}/plugins/">
                <include name="${path_to_jar}" />
            </fileset>
        </path>
        <property name="plugin_fullpath" refid="rfu.pfp" />
        <findbugs home="${FINDBUGS.HOME}" 
            output="xml:withMessages" 
            outputFile="${report.dir}/findbugs_report_${plugin}.xml" 
            timeout="1200000" 
            includefilter="report/YOUR_findbugs_filter.xml" 
            excludefilter="report/YOUR_findbugs_exclude_filter.xml" 
            jvmargs="-server -Xss1m -Xmx512m">

            <class location="${plugin_fullpath}" />
        </findbugs>
    </target>
```

Call the task:

**Unpacked plugin:**

```
<antcall target="run.findbugs.unpacked">
    <param name="plugin" value="com.myplugin.core" />
    <param name="path_to_jar" value="com.myplugin.core_*/*.jar" />
</antcall>
```

**plugin:**

```
<antcall target="run.findbugs">
    <param name="plugin" value="com.myplugin.core" />
</antcall>
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: Any chance of getting a sample of content from "report/YOUR_findbugs_exclude_filter.xml"?

Comment: There is a good example in the [official findbugs manual](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html).